# Why is sqlservr.exe Running?

Tags: sql-server, process

sqlserver.exe is running according to ProcessExplorer.  When I kill it, it comes back later.  Why?  I have disabled the service in Services, and it doesn't show as "Started" even though it is clearly running according to ProcessExplorer:

[image]

When I try to follow these directions:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187071(v=sql.105).aspx
I end up at a screen that also shows it's not running:

[image]

How can I stop it permanently without uninstalling anything?

Comment: What else is running in that box? Services that use SqlServer could be starting it (e.g. Sharepoint, Exchange). In Process Explorer, you could use the Process tree view to see which process started it (but if it was services.exe, that won't tell you much). You can also turn on a column called Process Timeline (under Select Columns, Process Performance) to see if that gives you any clue.

Comment: My comment above applies to SysInternals' Process Explorer (downloadable from Microsoft Technet).

Comment: Not running Sharepoint or Exchange (tons of other stuff though, this is my main work machine).  The process tree shows no parent for it, it's at the base level.  I don't see "Process Timeline", but I do see "Start Time" which shows a time yesterday morning.  I may try killing it again and see when it comes back in case I can put it together with something I did.

Comment: If it's on the base level in the tree, that means the process that started it has already exited. In my version (15.31) "Process Timeline" is right under "Start time"...

Comment: Exchange Server doesn't use SQL Server.

Comment: Okay, I killed sqlservr, went about my day, and at some point (after using visual studio and subversion and other applications) sqlservr.exe popped back up in process explorer.  And now the parent process is there, and it's visual studio.  That narrows it down quite a bit.

Comment: SqlServer.exe is just another executable - it can be started as a service but there's nothing magical and holy about code that can run as a service that prevents it being called as a conventional app too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can see SQL Server running in process explorer, try right-clicking on the line referring to it, choosing properties, and choosing the image tab.  [image]

The Parent may provide you with some insight as to what is starting the process.

Comment: Yeah, it's visual studio.  I'm trying to track down why VS is starting this now, and so far I see some people thinking it might be related to LocalDB.  That's all I've got right now.

Comment: Yeah, if you're using a local database, it's launching SQL Server for you.

Comment: But how am I using a local database?  Is it done automatically?  can it be turned off?  It's not something I set up on purpose.

Comment: I'd need to know more about what you're doing in VS to answer that.  My guess is that your project refers to a database at some point.

Comment: The project causing the problem is a database project.  Obvious in retrospect.  Still a little weird because I didn't think it used to start sqlservr.exe, but maybe I'm wrong.  The database project never actually talks to a real database server, so I wonder what it's using that exe for.  I guess I'll have to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server can automatically update or reinstall itself. The developer edition seems to be particularly bad for this behaviour. Also if you roll a windows feature update back the reinstall is automatic and mandatory. Reinstall on my i5-3230 takes about 36 hours to complete. After that the process closes. It can consume 60 to 80%cpu and do 35mb/s. luckily I have other machines. If I cancel it it restarts.